# Django Python Processing 2 Models in 1 form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-3.5

I want to extend the User model in Django by a couple new fields. After that, I need to create 1 form where you can register your username + password from the User model and also the fields from my custom model.

This is my model for the custom User fields:

```
class Gebruiker(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    voornaam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    achternaam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    gb_datum = models.DateField()
    plaats = models.CharField(max_length=52)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    huisnummer = models.IntegerField()
    nfid = models.IntegerField()
    hn_toevoeging = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.voornaam + self.achternaam
```

And this is my view for the form. In this  form I also want to add the fields for the Gebruiker model while keeping the rest of the form. How can I do this?

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'home/registration_form.html'
# display blank form
def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    # form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

# process form data
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)

        #cleaned/normalized data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        #returns User objects if credentials are correct
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home:index')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

My forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import Gebruiker

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

class GebruikerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Gebruiker
        fields = ('voornaam', 'achternaam')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you did for UserForm in Post def. I would send GebruikerForm and UserForm to display fields in the form and in the post initialize user form and Gebruikerform and check validation.

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST) and
Gform_class = Gebruikerform()
Gform = self.Gform_class(request.POST).
```

I use TemplateView for everything and this is how i usually do.

Comment: Could you eleborate a little further on what changes I should apply? I'm a noob at Django, thanks for the reply tho